# New garage door opener, can't push door down, rail buckles up instead

Tags: garage-door-opener, garage-door

I've installed a new garage door opener after my old one just stopped working. It's a [Genie PowerMax 1200](http://www.geniecompany.com/garage-door-openers/retail_powermax-1200.aspx)

I followed the instructions to a Tee. I have a solid door instead of a paneled door, so I installed the mounting rail bracket on header 6 inches over to door's highest point while opening.

The door bracket also needed to be attached slightly differently due to the one-piece door, but that's also done.

So now on to the clusterf*ck. When I went to initially close the door for the first time (you start in the up position) instead of pushing the door down, the whole rail went up 
and buckled. It's as though it needs more force to overcome the door's rolling friction resistance than the rail can handle and so it buckles.

Anyways, I managed to re-straighten the rail (I think), but now I just don't know what to do. Does anyone have any ideas.

I have giant springs on the side of my door, presumably those make it easier to lift the door up. Maybe they are adding to much resistance to get the door moving?

Thanks!

Comment: if you detach the door from the opener can you operate the door still (manually)?

Comment: Yea something is not fitted properly :( It should be easy to open and close manually

Comment: If detached from the opener the door opens fine. It's not easy to open but it's not hard either.

Comment: I'd start with improving door operation. I'd look at adjusting mounting height of the opener. If the old opener was chain drive, I'd consider using a like for like replacement. One piece doors are an edge case, and chains because they only operate in tension, tend to be, in my experience, more forgiving mechanically.